# Null Model Exception then returning View in .NET 5 ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, .net-5

[image: No Desc]

[image: No Desc]

Here I have screenshots then debugging. It looks that the model is not null, but after returning the view is says that is null. The var Page in the controller and the @model Page in the View are of same type (I've checked that). In production environment it just returns 404 (which means there is error and no result is returned).

Is this a .NET 5 bug? Do I have to report that as an issue at GitHub ?

Comment: do you have any global filters that could set the model to null after being returned from the controller method?

Comment: @KhanhTO I haven't meshed up with this things. The exact same code it was working perfectly , I thing it broke up after I switch to .NET 5

Comment: Things got even more tricky. After I clicked 3 times "continue" in the debugger the model just loaded as expected. I believe that it's not meant to be that way.

Comment: Can you share the related code or create a small sample to reproduce the problem? I have tried to test the code on my .NET 5 application, it seems that once the return Model is null, it will show this error. You could consider to check whether the Model is null in the view, then, if Model is not null, display the Model content, code as below: `if(Model != null){ ViewData["Title"] = Model.Title;}` and `@if (Model != null && Model.Title != null){@Html.Raw("<h2>" + Model.Title + "</h2>");}`.